# Entity Framework 5.0 is not including results

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a one to many relationships and I'm trying to get a result with the child collection.
But my result an empty list.

Here are my models

```
internal interface IEntity
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class Client : IEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public List<Pet> Pets { get; set; } = new List<Pet>();
}

public class Pet : IEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public Client Client { get; set; } = new Client();
    public Guid ClientId { get; set; }
}
```

And here my it is my context

```
public class PetShopDbContext : DbContext
{
    public PetShopDbContext()
    {

    }

    public PetShopDbContext(DbContextOptions<PetShopDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

    public virtual DbSet<Pet>? Pets { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Client>? Clients { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        optionsBuilder.LogTo(Console.WriteLine);
    }
}
```

And finally my startup

```
        services.AddDbContext<PetShopDbContext>(options =>
              options
                    .UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("PetShopConnection")));
```

I'm trying to use this way

```
    clients = dbContext.Clients.Include(p => p.Pets).ToList();
```

But the client.Pets reference is empty

I tried some lazy solutions without success.

Comment: Similar has been asked many times. Never initialize reference navigation properties with `new`. In your case, remove `= new Client();`

Comment: @IvanStoev Thank you! I did that because I'm using `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` functionality to warning possible null references. So without that, the compiler was giving the warning. My solution here was nullable property `List<Pet>?`.

Comment: It's ok (and actually recommended) to initialize **collection** navigation properties, but **reference** navigation properties should remain `null`. Use `= null!;` to avoid NRT warnings. See [Non-nullable properties and initialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/nullable-reference-types#non-nullable-properties-and-initialization) EF Core documentation topic.